# Returning a char pointer to a element of a struct

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, char

I'm designing a C API for a C++ library. I'm trying to supply to the user of this API access to the inner elements of a declared struct.

```cpp
struct MESH_path {
    char name[12];
    int nsize;
    char settings[20];
    int ssize;
};

struct MESH_path * MESH_API
MESH_path_new(uint8_t type, uint8_t belt) {
    struct MESH_path * context;
    context = new struct MESH_path;
    std::string mn = Mesh::name(
        static_cast<Mesh::Type>(type),
        static_cast<Belt::Type>(belt),
    );
    std::string ss = Mesh::settings(static_cast<Belt::Type>(belt));
    std::copy(mn.begin(), mn.end(), context->name);
    std::copy(ss.begin(), ss.end(), context->settings);
    context->nsize = mn.length();
    context->ssize = ss.length();
    return context;
}

char * MESH_path_name(struct * MESH_path context, int * size) {
    *size = context->nsize;
    return context->name;
}
```

Will the pointer become invalid when it leaves its declaring scope, i.e., when the function `MESH_path_name` returns?

Is my current implementation valid?
Can the user call it like:

```
struct MESH_path * context;
context = MESH_path_new(..., ...);
int* nsize;
char* name = MESH_path_name(context, &nsize);
```

and in the later code he can access the original string that was stored in the original struct via `char* name`. What would happen if the user tries to alter the memory pointed by `char* name`? Will it also alter the inner contents of `context`? How can I implement `MESH_path_name` in a way such the user cannot alter inner elements of `context`?

Comment: You must be thinking about what happens when you pass pointers to a function and modify the arguments in-place, something you have not done here.  Returning *anything* from a function allows it to escape from its enclosing scope.

Comment: The question "Is there any better way to implement this function" is not answerable without some idea of what you want to make "better."

Comment: "Alternative" is not any better than "better."  Of course there are "alternative" ways to implement any function.  You can give requirements to 25 different people, and they will come up with 25 different implementations.

Comment: `context` is a local var in `MESH_path_new`, it's unkown in `MESH_path_name`.

Comment: I forgot to add context as an argument to `MESH_path_name`

Comment: I already updated my question with the correct declaration of `MESH_path_name`